# Linq To XML problems and databinding

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, linq-to-xml

I try the linked data from an XML file to my WPF interface through Linq To XML. Below, the error returned and codes:

> The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'.

my codes

c#:

```
IEnumerable<string> datas = from d in XDocument.Load(@"Resources\limits.xml").Descendants("limits")
                                    where (int)d.Element("ID") == id
                                    select d.Elements;
```

XAML/WPF

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=explicationTitle}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=explicationDescription}" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="Aucune" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=explicationLimiteAucune}" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="Modérée" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=explicationLimiteModeree}" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="Totale" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=explicationLimiteTotale}" Margin="10" />
</StackPanel>
```

XML DATA FILE:

```
    <Limits xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Limit>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <title>Ma première limite :)</title>
    <description>NFC West</description>
    <explication>
      information
      de
      bla blabla
    </explication>
    <explicationTitle>Poney</explicationTitle>
    <explicationDescription>Description de la limitation</explicationDescription>
    <explicationLimiteAucune>Aucune limite..tout va bien :)</explicationLimiteAucune>
    <explicationLimiteModeree>Quelques soucis, rien de grave</explicationLimiteModeree>
    <explicationLimiteTotale>Gros soucis :)</explicationLimiteTotale>
  </Limit>
  <Limit>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <title>Limitation 2</title>
    <description>NFC West</description>
    <explication>
      information 2
      de 2
      bla blabla 2 2 2
    </explication>
    <explicationTitle>Poney</explicationTitle>
    <explicationDescription>Description de la limitation</explicationDescription>
    <explicationLimiteAucune>Aucune limite..tout va bien :)</explicationLimiteAucune>
    <explicationLimiteModeree>Quelques soucis, rien de grave</explicationLimiteModeree>
    <explicationLimiteTotale>Gros soucis :)</explicationLimiteTotale>
  </Limit>
</Limits>
```

How to create and databind with a nice linq to xml request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issue in your code.
First I like to mention that xml is case sensitive so please correct your query like below other wise you got this error:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element

change .Descendants("limits") to .Descendants("Limit")

Also you can use just var instead of IEnumerable and you will get all elements for that node

```
    var datas = from d in XDocument.Load(@"Resources\limits.xml").Descendants("Limit")
                where (int)d.Element("Id") == 1
                select d.Elements();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Elements` is a method and you forgot parenthesis over there so it should be `d.Elements()` but still you will get a conversion error  because `d.Elements` will return `IEnumerable<XElement>`  but you are trying to store it in `IEnumerable<String>`.

You can project the elements using anonymous type like this:-

```
var datas = from d in XDocument.Load(@"Resources\limits.xml").Descendants("limits")
            where (int)d.Element("ID") == id
            select new 
                 {
                    explicationTitle = (string)d.Element("explicationTitle"),
                    explicationDescription = (string)d.Element("explicationDescription"),
                    ..and so on
                 };
```

But I am not sure if anonymous type is suitable for a WPF grid (as I have no experience with that), in that case you can define a `Type` and project it instead of anonymous type, something like this:-

```
public class Limit
{
    public string explicationTitle { get; set; }
    public string explicationDescription{ get; set; }
}
```

Then you can project this type as:-

```
List<Limit> datas = (from d in XDocument.Load(@"Resources\limits.xml")
                                       .Descendants("limits")
                where (int)d.Element("ID") == id
                select new 
                  {
                    explicationTitle = (string)d.Element("explicationTitle"),
                    explicationDescription = (string)d.Element("explicationDescription"),
                    ..and so on
                  }).ToList();
```